# .NET 4.5 padding oracle vulnerability

Tags: .net, .net-4.5, padding-oracle-attack

We're using .NET 4.5.1 for a project which runs on IIS7. We're using webforms. Does the ASP.NET Padding Oracle Vulnerability still apply? I can not find any information on it.

When I browse to http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail;jsessionid=7F988C81C28DD9C0C8348D1A4B1791D1?vulnId=CVE-2010-3332&cid=1 .NET Framework 4.5 is not mentioned: "Microsoft .NET Framework 1.1 SP1, 2.0 SP1 and SP2, 3.5, 3.5 SP1, 3.5.1, and 4.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This vulnerability do not apply to .NET 4.5. There are [`hotfixes available`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/MS10-070) for previous versions of the framework.